# Is it possible to use select2 in datalist and how?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, sql-server, ajax

Currently I am using `select` to select the option that retrieve from database. But I want to provide another alternative where the user can type in the input when there is no desired option.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="createAppointmentContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control select2contact" id="createAppointmentContact" onchange="showOptions(this)"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ajax to get the option from database

```
$(".select2contact").select2({
    width: '100%',
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    allowClear: true,
    cache: true,
    multiple: false,
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    placeholder: '- Please Select -',
    ajax: {
        url: "../WS/wsCustomerDetails.asmx/GetCustomerDetailsList",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 200,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                searchKey: params.term || '',
                page: params.page || 1,
                pageLimit: 10,
                userID: getCookie('UserID')
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.items,
                pagination: {
                    more: data.morePages
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The SQL query

```
sqlQuery = string.Format(@"
     SELECT TotalCount = COUNT(Contact_ID) OVER(), 
     Contact_ID AS id, Contact_Name AS text
     FROM CustomerDetails
     WHERE IsDelete = 0 AND Contact_Name is not null {0}                        
     ORDER BY Contact_ID                            
     OFFSET " + (Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1).ToString() + "*" + pageLimit + " ROWS FETCH NEXT " + pageLimit + " ROWS ONLY", sqlSearch);
```

Is it possible to use select2 in datalist and how? If not, how to get the option from the database to the datalist and then insert the selected option to database?

Comment: try this results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
                                return { id: obj.id, text: obj.text};
                            })

Comment: @Bosco, may I know this is for what?

Comment: for result rendering

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [tagging](https://select2.org/tagging) or Dynamic Option Creation. Tagging can be enabled easily like this:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected">orange</option>
  <option>white</option>
  <option>purple</option>
</select>

$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
});
```

Comment: what is the suitable datatype? Previously I assigned int but I'm getting "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'tirah' to data type int."

Comment: What values do you need to be populated?